# Simple MYSQL Query returns multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure for my users and friends table.

```
users: first_name, last_name

friends: to_id, from_id, friend_status
```

So if users `4 and 7` are friends, I store them in the friend's table as `4 | 7 | 1` or `7 | 4 | 1` depending on who initiated the friendship. I do not do duplicate entries so 4 | 7 | 1 and 7 | 4 | 1 are not stored. Only one will be stored.

My problem is when I want to do a simple search for a friend whose name is Paul. Each of the following snippets below work fine by themselves but together, I get multiple rows that show inacurrate users who are not even friends.

```
SELECT u.* FROM `users` u, `friends` f WHERE CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) 
like '%paul%'  AND ((f.to_id=$logged_in_uid OR f.from_id=$logged_in_uid) 
AND f.friend_status=1);
```

Again, the above doesn't even return the friends, but the latter portion alone does bring back friends when used by itself.

Thanks and any help is truly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `JOIN Condition` between `u` and `f`.

could you try this?

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `users` u INNER JOIN `friends` f
    ON (u.user_id = f.to_id OR u.user_id = f.from_id) AND u.user_id != $logged_in_uid
WHERE CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) LIKE '%paul%'
    AND (
      (f.to_id=$logged_in_uid OR f.from_id=$logged_in_uid) 
      AND f.friend_status=1
    );
```

Or use `UNION` to get rid of `OR` which make things complicated and can't use index.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `users` u INNER JOIN `friends` f ON u.user_id = f.from_id
WHERE CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) LIKE '%paul%'
    AND f.to_id=$logged_in_uid AND f.friend_status=1

UNION

SELECT u.*
FROM `users` u INNER JOIN `friends` f ON u.user_id = f.to_id
WHERE CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) LIKE '%paul%'
    AND f.from_id=$logged_in_uid AND f.friend_status=1
```